# Laravel 6.2: How to change [from address] field in mail of Laravel

Tags: php, email, laravel-6.2

I am using Laravel 6.2 now.
I am sending the email using below code.

```
Mail::send('emails.sample',[],function($message) use($subject)
        {
            $message->subject($subject);
            $message->from('test@example.com', 'supplier');
            $message->to('user@hotmail.com'); // or user@gmail.com
        });
```

My .env is the following.

```
MAIL_DRIVER=sendmail
MAIL_HOST=smtp.myhost.server.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=test@example.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=password
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=test@example.com
MAIL_FROM_NAME=supplier
```

And config/mail.php is the following

```
'from' => [
        'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS', 'test@example.com'),
        'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME', 'supplier'),
],
```

but after receiving the email, sender email address is coming like this

> `supplier <xxx@myhost.server.com>`

As you see, changed sender name. but didn't changed sender email.

It should be `supplier <test@example.com>`.

How do I fix this? Any suggestions, Please!

King Regards!!!

Comment: Maybe sendmail adjusts the address? What happens when you set your driver to SMTP?

Comment: Do you have SPF/DKIM DNS records set for your domain? `example.com` will need to have those records set for mail clients to verify that mail coming from `smtp.myhost.server.com` is legitimate email. Otherwise, the mail client might only show the domain of the server that sent the message.

Comment: Seems relate to your smtp host as it's expected that sender has the same domain